# Subscription error that cannot subscript value of type

Tags: swift

I am converting my project from `Swift 2` to `Swift 3` and I am stuck with one weird error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [[String : AnyObject]]' (aka
>   'inout Array>')

What does the "inout" even mean in this error?

This is the code part:

```
var productsValue = [[String:AnyObject]]()
cell.snusProductImageView.kf.setImage(with: NSURL(string: productsValue[indexPath.row]["productUrl"] as! String)!)
```

What is causing this? I don't understand the error at all since it is so board. Can you guys help me?

I tried using `guard` and `let` but it doesn't work for some reason.

I understand that productsValue is a `[String:AnyObject]`. That means that`["productUrl"]` is an `AnyObject` and I can't assign an `AnyObject` where a `[String:AnyObject]` is expected. But why it worked in `Swift 2`?

Comment: Try `Any` instead of `AnyObject`

Comment: I already tried but errors stays same just with Any instead of AnyObject :(

Comment: What is `cell.snusProductImageView.kf` ?

Comment: `cell` is declared tableview cell, `snusProductImageView` is `imageview` and `kf` is kingfisher library.

Comment: Try so split the expression: `let url = NSURL(string: productsValue[indexPath.row]["productUrl"] as! String)!` and `cell.snusProductImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)` – which part causes the error?

Comment: Like this the second part but error is totally different: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'Resource?'` Which is absolutely true I think :D

Comment: I have no experience with that library, but according to the ReadMe, `setImage(with:)` takes a URL parameter, not NSURL.

Comment: You are absolutely right but no matter if I use NSURL or URL the error is still same. In my case I had to do some convertions to make it work with Firebase. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error like this:

```
var productsValue = [[String:AnyObject]]()
if productsValue[indexPath.row]["productUrl"] != nil {
   var productValue = self.productsValue[indexPath.row]["productUrl"] as! String
   cell.snusProductImageView.kf.setImage(with: NSURL(string: productValue) as! Resource?)
}
```

I don't know if this fixes it and why does it silence the error but yeah.

Comment: Initailizers are functions, so the () makes it a function call. Maybe it'll be clearer if you read it this way: `var productsValue = Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>()`, or `var productsValue = Array<...>()`. Similarly to `var something = Thing()`. The confusion arises because array literals like `[1,2,3]` look a lot like array initializers `[]()`.